# Wordpress admin bar user menu location / file

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

Can anyone tell me the location of user menu on the Wordpress admin bar? I would like to move the dropdown menu (includes profile, notifications, messages, etc) to another part of the site. Thanks!

UPDATED: Looking for the actual PHP file where the "Howdy, admin" + avatar section is located, if that's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link will help you alter admin menus ,https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/customizing-your-wordpress-admin--wp-24941

Refer this link too, https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Admin_Bar

```
WP_Admin_Bar is located in wp-includes/class-wp-admin-bar.php.


i) admin_bar_init - This action hook is called at the very end of initialization.

ii) add_admin_bar_menus - This action hook is called at the end of the public add_menus() method.
```

Comment: Sorry I meant the actual PHP file where the "Howdy, admin" + avatar section is located